# Symbol with private identifier argument

Tags: dart, symbols, dart-editor, dart-analyzer

I want to create a symbol equal to that of a private MethodMirror's simplename. However, Symbol's documentation states the argument of new Symbol must be a valid public identifier. If I try and create a `const Symbol('_privateIdentifier')` dart editor informs me that evaluation of this constant expression will throw an exception - though the program runs fine, and I am able to use it without any issues.

```dart
void main(){
  //error flagged in dart editor, though runs fine.
  const s = const Symbol('_s');
  print(s); //Symbol("_s");
}
```

It seems the mirror system uses symbols.

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';
class ClassA{
  _privateMethod(){}
}

void main(){
  var classMirror = reflect(new ClassA()).type;
  classMirror.declarations.keys.forEach(print);
  //Symbol("_privateMethod"), Symbol("ClassA")
}
```

Is the documentation/error flagging in dart editor a legacy bug due to an outdated dart analyzer? Or are there plans to enforce this public requirement in future? Is there another way to create a unique identifying symbol that will be minified to the same symbol as the declaration's simple name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it doesn't throw then the VM has a bug in the const Symbol constructor.

The problem is that "_s" does not identify a private variable without also saying which library it belongs to. The symbol constructor has a second argument taking a `LibraryMirror` for that reason, and passing in a private name without also passing in a mirror should throw.
That's hard to do in a const constructor without side-stepping the requirements of a const constructor (no executing code!), which is likely why the VM doesn't handle it. It needs to be special-cased at the compiler level.

You will also find that `const Symbol('_s')` is not the same as `#_s`. The latter creates a private symbol for the current library, the former (if it runs) creates a non-private symbol with the name '_s', which is not really useful. For example `print(identical(#_s, const Symbol('_s')));` prints false.

Comment: Is it possible to have a symbol literal that is identical to a top-level setter-method? From what I understand, setter symbols always end in "=", but it looks like #x= gets tokenized into [#x, =].

Comment: A setter `Symbol` can't be created using a symbol literal, but it can be created using `const Symbol("x=")`. That's issue http://dartbug.com/13640. It makes it somewhat harder to create a private setter symbol, and if it doesn't have to be a constant, the easiest way is likely to create an object with a `noSuchMethod` that leaks the `Invocation.memberName` symbol.

Answer (score 1):

The To get hold of the symbol I think you would need to get it from the object. e.g.

```
  reflect(thing).type.declarations.keys.firstWhere(
    (x) => MirrorSystem.getName(x) == "_privateThingIWant");
```