# flutter Text exception - expression is not a valid compile-time constant

Tags: dart, constants, flutter

I'm trying to understand the `List` [example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/list_demo.dart) in [flutter_gallery](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/flutter_gallery).
My approach is to simplify the `` code by refactoring into ([my project](https://github.com/jeffhongxiao/flutter_gallery_material_list)).

I'm seeing a breaking change in [this commit](https://github.com/jeffhongxiao/flutter_gallery_material_list/commit/c6c13e5f8e98305aa7c30126a894e295876e5b65)

```
I/flutter (14712): 'file:///Users/hong/Flutter/github/flutter_gallery_material_list/lib/main.dart': error: line 54:
I/flutter (14712): expression is not a valid compile-time constant
I/flutter (14712):     const Text t = const Text(text);
```

The source code starting line 53 is:

```
  MergeSemantics _mergeSemanticsOf(String text, _MaterialListType listType) {
    const Text t = const Text(text);
    //const Text t = const Text('we want a variable here');
    return new MergeSemantics(
      child: new ListTile(
          dense: true,
          title: t,
          trailing: new Radio<_MaterialListType>(
            value: listType,
            groupValue: _itemType,
            onChanged: changeItemType,
          )),
    );
  }
```

I can only make it compile with something like:
`const Text t = const Text('we want a variable here');`.

I understand what the exception says, but wonder if there is a way to pass a variable to Text().

This is the exception popup (in a red box) in VSCode:
[image]

And this is the exception on an Android phone (Samsung S7)
[image]

A search on Stackoverflow shows [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29113434/symbol-with-private-identifier-argument), which looks not related to my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Constants (i.e. `const`) in Dart are *compile-time*, that is, they must not rely on the runtime of your application in anyway, and can only be simple side-effect free constructor invocations (i.e. `const` constructors) or literals like strings, numbers, and lists/maps.

For example, *this* is a compile-time string:

```
const version = 'v1.0.0';
```

And I could use it below:

```
const Text(version)
```

Dart supports *limited* expressions as well, as compile-time constants:

```
const Text('My version is: $version')
```

However in your example, `text` is not a compile-time constant.

Lets view this through a simpler example, called `showMyName`:

```
Widget showMyName(String name) => const Text(name);
```

This will get an identical error to what you saw, because we're trying to create a *compile-time* constant `Text` from a runtime provided value (the argument `name`). Of course, we don't *need* `Text` to be a compile-time constant. You can simply use `new`:

```
Widget showMyName(String name) => new Text(name);
```

In future versions of Dart (with `--preview-dart-2`), you can omit `new`:

```
Widget showMyName(String name) => Text(name);
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. i fixed the issue by using `Text t = new Text(text);` per your suggestions. the commit is [here](https://github.com/jeffhongxiao/flutter_gallery_material_list/commit/cf92a29dfbe13e0c979a299d3a2414d97e417f04)

Answer (score 0):

Here  const Text t = const Text(text) you are using a const constructor. The compiler is expecting a compile time constant and is raising issue because the arguments you are passing in are not constant but depend on the runtime value of text.

If you simply remove the const keyword it will compile without errors.